# работа со списком пайтон

Tags: python

как умножить число в переменной на список. К примеру у нас есть список в котором лежат числа 1000 и я хочу переменную в которой лежит число умножить на этот список чтобы произвести математические операции
список с числом    ;
переменная с числом;
переменная * список

Comment: Хорошо бы приводить примеры, из словесного описания не всегда всё понятно

Answer (score 1):

Если на "чистом" питоне, то можно использовать **списковое включение**:

```
a = 10
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
c = [a * x for x in b]
print(c)

# [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Но лучше для действий с векторами и матрицами использовать библиотеку `Numpy`, она сама всё правильно сделает:

```
import numpy as np

a = 10
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
c = a * b
print(c)

# [10 20 30 40 50]
```

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы. Но мне кажется лучший совет ТС -  это начать изучать Python. Умножение элементов списка на число обычно изучают на втором или третьем занятии.  Если ТС задает такие вопросы, то могу только со страхом представить, что будет завтра. Я бы такие вопросы закрывал "На взлете".

Comment: @passant Ну так то да, вы правы, конечно. )